# SQL - How to select a row having a column with max value in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
date            value
18/5/2010        40
18/5/2010        20
20/5/2010        60
18/5/2010        30
17/5/2010        10
16/5/2010        40
18/5/2010        60
18/5/2010        25
```

**Output**

```
date           value
18/5/2010        60
20/5/2010        60
```

I need to query for the row having max(value)(i.e. 60). So, here we get two rows. 
the date can be in any order

Plz do not use **rownum**  and **subquery**
 I need a dynamic query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
select *
from table
where value = (select max(value) from table);
```

Comment: @mayank above query will give what you want

Comment: That's what i needed solution without rownum

Comment: An optimized solution does not depend only on a query. It also depends on what indexes you have available, statistics etc. The least you should have in this scenario is an index on the `value` column.

Comment: Actually i have an table which contain more than 20000 rows i have to select 8 columns by using  various conditions in where clause  so ... That is why i needed my it's solution without sub query ... So can u plz do that

Answer (score 1):

`select * from (select * from table 
order by value desc, date_column) 
where rownum = 1;`

Answering the question more specifically:

`select high_val, my_key
from (select high_val, my_key
      from mytable
      where something = 'avalue'
      order by high_val desc)
where rownum <= 1`

Answer (score 0):

This works and is quite simple:

```
SELECT MAX(value)
FROM table
```

Comment: And it is wrong.
He specifically said "I need to query for the row having max(value)" - not just the max value but the entire row.