# Oracle SQL Find max digit in number in cell

Tags: sql, string, oracle, max, recursive-query

I have a column like that :

[image]

How can I find the max digit column? ( I want to select the max digit from the left column and write it to a new column)

WITH ORACLE SQL

THANKS!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL - How to select a row having a column with max value in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608862/sql-how-to-select-a-row-having-a-column-with-max-value-in-oracle)

Comment: @PM77-1 No, the link is irrelevant to what OP wants.

Comment: Have you checked `translate` solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving it like a pro:

Creating sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE tab as
WITH t(col) AS
(
 SELECT 134425  FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 6453356 FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 65267   FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 9999    FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 467533  FROM dual
)
SELECT * FROM t;
```

Solution:

```
select * from tab,
lateral
( 
    select max(substr(col, level, 1)) max_digit
    from   dual
    connect by level <= length(col)
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: that works like a charm! thank you bro! you made my day!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a brute force method as well:

```
select (case when column like '%9%' then 9
             when column like '%8%' then 8
             . . . 
        end)
```

I mention this because a recursive query is not necessarily needed for this.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a recursive query to split the number into digits. A recursive query comes handy for this:

```
with cte (col, val, pos, maxpos) as (
    select col, substr(col, 1, 1), 1, length(col) from mytable
    union all
    select col, substr(col, pos + 1, 1), pos + 1, maxpos from cte where pos < maxpos
)
select col, max(val) max_digit
from cte 
group by col
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2ffe9ff3dc57faffd713a8aec20919bc)**:

```
    COL | MAX_DIGIT
------: | :--------
6453356 | 6        
   9999 | 9        
  65267 | 7        
 467533 | 7        
 134425 | 5
```

Comment: could you solve this by  "create table" not "with"  , I do not understand how it works. thank you so much!

Comment: @determinator: the cte puts each digit in a separate row. You change the outer query to `select * from cte order by col, pos` to see what it returns and understand the logic.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using Hierarchical query along with `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` function in order to split each digits individually first, and then find the maximum digit values for each grouped column values :

```
SELECT col, MAX( REGEXP_SUBSTR(col,'[^\d]',level) ) AS maxdigit
  FROM t
 CONNECT BY level <= LENGTH(col)
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
    AND PRIOR col = col
 GROUP BY col
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=62dbb926330954d8fa8537ac985a1763)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

but you can do it much easier and shorter: without any subqueries, CTE and connect-by.

just using `translate`, `length` and `rtrim`:

```sql
length(
   rtrim(
      translate(
        translate('0123456789',your_number,'          ')
       ,' 0123456789'
       ,'x          '
       )))-1 as max_number
```

Step-by-step description:

1. `translate('0123456789',x,'          ')` removes from '0123456789' existing digits. Lets call it `remove_existing`
2. `translate(remove_existing, ,' 0123456789','x          ')`  replaces spaces in remove_existing with 'x'. So you by position of X which digits exist in your number, for example 'x x x x xx' means that you have '0 2 4 6 89' in your number. Let's call it `existing_as_x`
3. `length(rtrim(existing_as_x))-1` removes spaces from right and returns length, so returned length-1 is equal to your required maximum digit.

Full test case:

```sql
with t(x) as (
select * from table(sys.odcinumberlist(
134425,
6453356,
65267,
9999,
467533
))
)
select 
x,
translate('0123456789',x,'          ') remove_existing,
translate(
    translate('0123456789',x,'          ')
   ,' 0123456789','x          '
   ) as existing_as_x,
length(
   rtrim(
      translate(
        translate('0123456789',x,'          ')
       ,' 0123456789'
       ,'x          '
       )))-1 as max_number
from t;
```

Results:

```sql
         X REMOVE_EXISTING  EXISTING_AS_X MAX_NUMBER
---------- ---------------- ------------- ----------
    134425 0     6789        xxxxx                 5
   6453356 012    789          xxxx                6
     65267 01 34   89         x  xxx               7
      9999 012345678                 x             9
    467533 012     89          xxxxx               7
```

Comment: Oh, that's really nice. !! I must thank you for thinking extra and coming up with a novel approach. I guess, it must be the fastest of all the solutions offered so far. Only testing can prove it, though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this one is a fastest solution from all posted as for now, but you can check it on `select level x from dual connect by level<=1e6` - just sum maximum digits on such generated data set (1mln rows)